# Splitting a data file into separate files using python

Tags: python

I have a text file that is formatted as shown below. I want to split each block of text starting from 
'# Data Written' into separate text files.

How do I go about this?
I'm sure a few lines of python code could do this, but I'm not a pythonista, alas. 
Suggestions, please.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume this is something along the lines of what you were looking for?

```
f = open('filename.txt', 'r')

databaseRaw = f.read()

database = databaseRaw.split('# Data Written')

f.close()

database.remove('')

for i in range(0, len(database)) :
    database[i] = '# Data Written'+''.join(database[i])

for i in range(0, len(database)) :
    f = open("output.txt"+ str([i]) ,"w+")
    f.write(database[i])
    f.close()
```

**EDIT : Figured out the problem I had had before, works fine now.**

it will create a new file per block, starting at 0, and if it creating a new line at the of end each file is an issue, I can make an easy way to remove it.

Comment: @ioio Is this what you were looking for?

Comment: I could probably make it work, but database.remove(' ') generates an error.  And I need the split blocks in separate output files.  Thank for your input.

Comment: @ioio You can just remove that part and it should still work. I had been using it for my test file since some of the outputs had come up with nothing.

Comment: I deleted the offending part. I think I can work this out from here with a bit more thinking :)

Comment: @ioio It works fine for me, creating a new file per block, not sure why it wouldn't work otherwise. You will be able to figure it out though, have fun!

Comment: @ CanadianCaleb  It's working now. I just had to correct the delimiter to align with what's in the file. All good! Many thanks!